# How to Check out from Git (on shared folder) in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio

Using Android 1.1.0, I am trying to check out an existing project from a Git repository that I have on a shared folder (Windows SMB/CIFS).

The problem is that **Android Studio only accepts URLs**, despite the fact that I have been working with non-URL (UNC, drive letter, or both) `git` repositories for a while, using `cygwin`'s git, from the command line.

For example, if I type an **existing** drive-letter-based path, it warns me *"The parent path must exist"*:

[image]

But I know it exists! So I continue and click the `Test` button. It then fails with *"Repository test has failed"*:

[image]

Is there a way, in Android Studio, to check out from a git repository located on a **shared folder**?

**Note:** That `.git` repository on a shared folder works very well using cygwin's command line and [TortoiseGit](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/).

Comment: You could try using a `file://` URL, such as `file:///z:/workspace/.git`

Comment: Thank you. That is an excellent idea. Unfortunately, I just tried this and it still fails with *"Repository test has failed"*.

Comment: Oh wait! I missed the extra `/`. There should be 3 slashes, not two. i.e. `///`. It just succeeded. Can you post your comment as answer so that I can accept it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an application that requires URLs, you can specify the location to a local repository as a `file://` URL, for example:

```
file:///z:/workspace/.git
```

Note (as you did, but this is for other folks who find their way there) that there are *three* slashes after `file:`.